# select two different counts sum from the same table

Tags: mysql, sql, count, aggregate-functions

I have a following table:

```
id  | R_ID  | is_assigned
-----------------
1   | X1    | 1
2   | X1    | 0
3   | X1    | 0
4   | X1    | 0
```

I want to get two different `COUNT()` values: one for all rows that belong to `group X1`. And next for rows that belong to `group X1` and `are not assigned, i.e. is_assigned value 0`.

Output:

```
R_ID  | Total Records  | Remaining
----------------------------------
X1    | 4              | 3
```

This is as far as I could get:

```
SELECT t1.r_id, COUNT(t1.*) as total_records
FROM tasks t1
GROUP BY r_id
```

How do I get another `count`?

Comment: `sum(1 - is_assigned) as Remaining`

Comment: as the first count but with WHERE is_assigned=0

Comment: If you don't have a PRIMARY KEY, you don't really have a table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation.  I would recommend writing this in MySQL as:

```
SELECT t1.r_id, COUNT(*) as total_records,
       SUM(t1.is_assigned = 0) as remaining
FROM tasks t1
GROUP BY t1.r_id
```